# Match multiple patterns in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have two types of error messages in the below format:

```
[2017-05-25 01:00:00,647][ERROR][marvel.agent.exporter.local] local exporter [default_local] - failed to delete indices
RemoteTransportException[[data-0][10.0.0.8:9300][indices:admin/delete]]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no such index];

[2017-05-18 00:00:06,339][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [data-2] [data-may-2017,data-apr-2017,data-mar-2017] failed to create
[data-may-2017,data-apr-2017,data-mar-2017]
```

My logstash configuration is like this:

```
input {
      file {
            path => "D:\logstash\logstash-2.4.0\bin\logs.txt"
            start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
  }

}
filter {
   grok {
        match => [ "message", "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:SERVERNAME}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)", "message",  "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}%{SPACE}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)"]
   }

}
output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

For Both the logs it is taking only the first grok pattern. Why it is not taking the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Seems my first grok pattern is matching all the logs , so thats why logstash is taking only the first pattern. So that i had used the below config with if condition which is working fine.

```
input {
      file {
            path => "D:\logstash\logstash-2.4.0\bin\logs.txt"
            start_position => "beginning"
             type => "log"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
  }

}
    filter {
      if [type] == "log" {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}%{SPACE}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)"]
        }
    # DEBUG Logs
    if "grokked" not in [tags] and "DEBUG" == [LEVEL] {
    grok { match => [ "ERRORMESSAGE", "(?m)^\[%{DATA:SERVERNAME}\]" ]
    add_tag => [ "Debug Logs", "grokked" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ ]
    }
    }
    }
    }
output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was:

> Why it is not taking the second one?

Answer is here:

```
filter {
   grok {
        match => [ "message", "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:SERVERNAME}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)", "message",  "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}%{SPACE}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ 
   }

}
```

You don't have to specify source multiple times, just once.

What you did now was:

```
["message", "pattern", "message", "pattern"]
```

While in reality it has to be:

```
["message", "pattern", "pattern", ..., "pattern"]
```

Comment: You want to try like this `match => [ "message", "(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:SERVERNAME}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)","(?m)^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:ERRORTYPE}%{SPACE}\]%{SPACE}(?<ERRORMESSAGE>(.|\r|\n)*)"]`